# Phpstorm codeigniter autocomplete custom models

Tags: php, codeigniter, properties, phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm on the job with PhpStorm and CodeIgniter.

Someday I saw `https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers` and applied it.

Autocomplete of controller, model and active record works fine.

But `PHPDOC @property in "my_models.php"` not works.

My project has goods_model and I added "`@property Goods_model $goods_model"` into

```
my_models.php.
```

I'm using CI 2.2.0 and PhpStorm 8.0.2.

I found `https://github.com/topdown/phpStorm-CC-Helpers/issues/6` this question,

and that seems very like my case.

Nobody know about this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Yesterday i installed PHPstrom, because of this problem i came back to netbeans. in netbeans just define property in any controller or model, parent controller or models works fine

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using PhpStorm since 3 years before..

Comment: I am also having issues with new models, I think it should work out of the box because it is very popular framework.